# CSVSwift - only last row of array displays in UITextView

Tags: swift, csv

Im trying out SwiftCSV so I can read in a .csv file and show some of its contents in a UITextView. Im not sure the UITextView is the way to go but I want the UI to be able to handle multiple lines of text.
The following code:

```
        do {
            // From a file
            let csvFile: CSV = try CSV(name: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pokemon", ofType: "csv")!)
            
            try csvFile.enumerateAsArray { array in
                print(array[1])
                self.textView.text = array[1]
            }
       }
```

The console output will print out the entire column of 700 items, but the UITextView only contains the last item only. The UI element is created in storyboards. It seems odd that array[1] shows different results here.

Comment: "print out the entire column of 700 items"  700 columns?  Really?  Not 700 rows?

Comment: The column has 700 rows

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
self.textView.text.append("\(array[1])\n")
```